# Choosing eigenvectors for SVD (or EVD)

Tags: linear-algebra, diagonalization, singular-values

I'd like to find the SVD for the following matrix:
$$\left(\begin{array}{cc}
5 & 5\\
-1 & 7
\end{array}\right)$$

I've calculated the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of $XX^{T}$ and the eigenvectors of $X^{T}X$, arriving at 
$$X=\left(\begin{array}{cc}
5 & 5\\
-1 & 7
\end{array}\right)=U\Sigma V^{T}=\left(\begin{array}{cc}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\\
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}
\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{cc}
\sqrt{80} & 0\\
0 & \sqrt{20}
\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{cc}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{10}} & -\frac{3}{\sqrt{10}}\\
\frac{3}{\sqrt{10}} & \frac{1}{\sqrt{10}}
\end{array}\right)^{T}$$
This does not work. However if I multiply the second column of $U$ by -1:
$$\left(\begin{array}{c}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\\
-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}
\end{array}\right)\mapsto\left(\begin{array}{c}
-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\\
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}
\end{array}\right)$$ 
Everything works out.

The question is why? Both are normalized orthogonal eigencectors, shouldn't either one work? How do I choose?

Comment: A similar question was asked and answered [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2069093/81360).  Perhaps you'll find my answer there satisfactory.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom. I somehow missed that one searching for an answer, and it indeed answers the question, thanks. Should I delete this one?

Comment: Leave it up; we'll just mark yours as a duplicate.  As you said, searching for the right post is hard, and having these duplicates around makes things easier.